# Broken laptop key attachmment

Tags: keyboard

Is there a universal laptop key support. I have new key and hinge but pins are broken. How can I fix or adapt?

Answer (score 1):

All it took was a single search query >_>

I've used [LaptopKey.com](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=Laptop%20Keys%20Replacement)'s service before. It's pretty much what is says on the tin.